# What is the purpose of subroutes when we can achieve through normal routes in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

Is there any specific reason for using subroutes in SAPUI5.

```
 {
                       pattern: "album/{catIndex}",
                       name: "songs",
                       view: "songlist",
                       viewLevel : 3,
                       targetAggregation: "masterPages" ,
                       subroutes: [
                                   {
                                       pattern: "category/{catIndex}/subcat/{subCatIndex}",
                                       name: "Products",
                                       view: "songdetails",
                                       viewLevel : 4,
                                       targetAggregation: "detailPages",
                                   }]
                   }
```

Here I have used subroutes, to get the scope of the model from routes to subroute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look at the documentation: If a subroute is hit, it will fire routeMatched event for all its parents. The routePatternMatched event will only be fired for the subroute not the parents. The routing will also display all the targets of the subroutes and its parents.